# Plesk new Subscription prob

Tags: plesk

i have created a new subscription in my plesk 
in the subscription it gave me only only 2 options

http://www.zimagez.com/full/cd5e0e8d4f1e1dea817defaa1cf6b754a58a1804b49417bb6924c0fb25bf0a9d93a9ed30c54fbccf360bd1a71e4a7d488a1c1636aa170a7c.php

- 10.0.0.1 (shared)
- 10.0.0.2 (dedicated)

in the DNS Zone i have this http://www.zimagez.com/zimage/screenshot-15052015-223929.php

it is ok if it gave me  a private IP 10.0.0.1 .

and i have this problem when i want to connect with FTP Client(FileZilla)

```
Statut :    Résolution de l'adresse de esmartconcepts.net
Statut :    Connexion à 10.0.0.1:21...
Erreur :    Délai d'attente expiré
Erreur :    Impossible d'établir une connexion au serveur
```

and this problem when i want to test the website esmartconcepts.net

http://www.zimagez.com/full/83a754f9f26549c8817defaa1cf6b7544175f5252fb316716924c0fb25bf0a9d93a9ed30c54fbccffc1fdb02de6ad190c63f773cbdc01e1b.php

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a private IP address like `10.0.0.1` to host your site. This site should now be accessible if you can access a site like http://10.0.0.1/ but this works only in your private machine or VPS and not anywhere else.

You need to change the IP address to a public IP Address in order for others to access the site. I guess this should be asked in ServerFault, rather than StackOverflow.